# Node.js http.client incomplete HTML

Tags: node.js, http

I've a simple `http` client in Node.js

```
http.request({host : "www.google.fr", path : "/"}, function(response) {
    // http ok(200)
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        // end here but html is incomplete sometimes
    });
});
```

I'm also checking `req.on('error'..)`, and the timeout.
In 99.9% of case everythings is going ok.
But sometimes, the server is giving me an incomplete HTML.
The socket is ok, the http response code is 200.
Where could it come from, The http server?

Comment: post some source codes, this sample works on 100%, problem can be if you use `nodemon` or some restart server, check if you have updated node to last version, also problem can be in your browser?

Comment: i'm not using nodemon or a browser

Comment: As per node.js [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback): With http.request() one must always call req.end() to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.